# Explain the Regular Expression /^[a-zA-Z ]*/

Tags: php, regex, string

I understand that the regex pattern must match a string which starts with the combination and the repetition of the following characters:

1. `a-z`
2. `A-Z`
3. `a white-space character`

And there is no limitation to how the string may end!

---

#### First Case

So a string such as `uoiui897868` (any string that only starts with space, `a-z` or `A-Z`) matches the pattern... (Sure it does)

#### Second Case

But the problem is a string like `76868678jugghjiuh` (any string that only starts with a character other than space, `a-z` or `A-Z`) matches too! **This should not happen!**

---

I have checked using the php function `preg_match()` too , which returns true (i.e. the pattern matches the string).
Also have used other online tools like `regex101` or `regexr.com`. The string does match the pattern.
Can anybody could help me understand why the pattern matches the string described in the second case?

Comment: The `^` means "beginning of string", so the regex means "starts with" any number of letters or spaces.  Note that the `*` means "0 or more".

Comment: And `*` means "any number of", including zilch.

Comment: You must have something else going on, testing at http://regexpal.com on your second example *does not match*.

Comment: No actually the `*` means 0 or more letters or spaces.  If it is not a letter or space then it matches 0 times :-)

Comment: http://regex101.com is a good regex tester with explanation.

Comment: @JayBlanchard: It actually *does* match.  It just happens to match zero characters, so it's not shown.

Comment: True @RocketHazmat :) I stand corrected.

Comment: yea!! i totally get that... here the pattern must **start with** only **any number of** spaces,a-z or A-Z **not any numeric character** ... as it does.... That's where i am stuck !!

Comment: regex101.com shows 1 match... but not where

Comment: @probuddhasingha: The issue is that 0 is "any number".  The 2nd has 0 spaces/letters, so it matches the `*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is completely useless: it will trivially match **any** string (empty, non-empty, with numbers, without,...), regardless of its structure.

This because

- with `^`, you enforce the begin of the string, now every string has a start.
- You use a group `[A-Za-z ]`, but you use a `*` operator, so `0` or more repititions. Thus even if the string does not contain (or begins with) a character from `[A-Za-z ]`, the matcher will simply say: zero matches and parse the remaining of the string.

You need to use `+` instead of `*` to **enforce** *"at least one character"*.

Answer (score 6):

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]*/
```

Your regex will match strings that "begin with" *any* number (including zero) of letters or spaces.

`^` means "start of string" and `*` means "zero or more".

Both `uoiui897868` and `76868678jugghjiuh` start with 0 or more letters/spaces, so they both match.

You probably want:

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]+/
```

The `+` means "one or more", so it won't match zero characters.

Answer (score 2):

The '*' quantifier on the end means zero or more matches of the character, so all strings will match.  Perhaps you want to drop the wildcard quantifier, or change it to a '+' quantifier, and add a '$' on the end to test the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want is to match *one* or more of the preceding characters.

For that you use `+`

```
/^[a-zA-Z ]+/
```